# Does installing rpm twice change file date/time?

Tags: rpm

I use "rpm -ivh --force mine.rpm" to install rpm on my system, but I notice that when I run this on the same rpm twice, I do not see the file date change. Is this expected? The file date/time, I mean, is what "ls -l" displays.

Comment: What do you mean by 'install an rpm twice'? Usually that is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. An RPM is like any other archive - the file date will be the date the file was built (on the RPM building machine). Using "`--force`" is a problem for another question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, but why in this case I get consistent updating for "**time of last change**" value?

Is this reliable method for getting understanding when rpm package was installed? I have to compare "**hp.drv.gz**" file with the other and "**hp.drv.gz**" is updated by rpm package manager.

```
rm /usr/share/cups/ppd/hp/hp.drv.gz
rpm -U --force /root/packages/print-driver-data-1.2.15-1.armv7l.rpm
stat -c "%x %y %z" /usr/share/cups/ppd/hp/hp.drv.gz 
2013-05-21 22:30:50.000000000 +0400 2013-05-21 22:30:50.000000000 +0400 2013-05-21 23:23:26.320005301 +0400

rpm -U --force /root/packages/print-driver-data-1.2.15-1.armv7l.rpm
stat -c "%x %y %z" /usr/share/cups/ppd/hp/hp.drv.gz 
2013-05-21 22:30:50.000000000 +0400 2013-05-21 22:30:50.000000000 +0400 2013-05-21 23:24:42.715005338 +0400
```